# An impossibly large calculation (programming puzzle)

Tags: python, algorithm

I have been trying to solve this programming puzzle I got at an interview for some days already, but haven't been able to make any progress.

It's originally written in pseudocode but i transcripted to python to work with it.

**What would be the result of executing the following code, taking into account that the device has the necessary resources to complete its execution?**

```
def solvePuzzle(N):
    var_A = 1
    var_B = 1
    var_C = 1
    var_D = 1

    for i in range(1, N + 1):
        result = 3 * var_D + 1 * var_C + 4 * var_B + 1 * var_A
        var_A = var_B
        var_B = var_C
        var_C = var_D
        var_D = result

    return var_D % 10000000000  # Last 10 digits of var_D


result_10 = solvePuzzle(10)
print(result_10)  # 902441
result_100 = solvePuzzle(100)
print(result_100)  # 8042318513
result_large = solvePuzzle(2023 ** 100)  # 2023^100
print(result_large)  # result??
```

---

If anyone has a clue of how to solve it, or knows any information source where i could search about it i'd be so grateful. I'd rather solve it by myself if it's possible!

I tried with some big numbers to check if for bigger values the 10 last digits would stay static, but still changed and couldn't test any bigger values since my PC would crash.

Also considered what would be the limit of the max value of the number variable type used, but since the puzzle didn't specify any language, it's not related to the max value of the number type.

Asked ChatGPT for any clue but answered it's incapable to calculate neither give any advice on how to solve it.

Comment: The algorithm appears to be based on the typical O(N) algorithm for obtaining the Tetranacci numbers....

Comment: You should ask on https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Scarabee, the OP mentioned that it is a programming puzzle, they probably want to solve it using programming.

Comment: Code snippet looks like python.  Why don't you just load it into an IDE and run it for an answer?

Comment: @itprorh66 They said they did try it and it crashed (no wonder, with such huge N).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. This site isn't for advice per se; please ask a specific question instead; see [ask]. A good question could maybe be something like, "How can I simplify a calculation involving really big numbers?"  and you could mention the fact that there's a modulus at the end and that the calculation is iterative.

Comment: How could there be grounds to reopen this? "Any advice?" is as open-ended (and far from being a narrow, specific question) as things get.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy That's the title. Yes, it's a bad title. But what they then ask is *"What would be the result of executing the following code, taking into account that the device has the necessary resources to complete its execution?"* That's very narrow, and easily answerable.

Comment: @KellyBundy, A good title would serve as a demonstration of feasibility of extracting and describing a narrow, specific problem someone else might also have. As such, the very act of building a good title would help convince me that the question is in fact on-topic -- because it would show that there _is_ an underlying question that can be succinctly described, other than just asking someone else to perform a mathematical exercise on the OP's behalf. Yes, it's answerable; but I'm not convinced there's a narrow, specific question _about the practice of software development_ here.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Alright, although I think *"just asking someone else to perform a mathematical exercise on the OP's behalf"* is mischaracterizing them. To me it sounds like they did try a few things and weren't just lazy. And they asked for clues and said *"I'd rather solve it by myself if it's possible!"*.

Answer (score 5):

## Result

The result would be 3548910009. The calculation with my scripts took less than a second.

## Idea

Represent the iteration step as multiplication with a matrix:

```
                               |0 0 0 1|
                               |1 0 0 4|
next |A B C D|  =  |A B C D| * |0 1 0 1|
                               |0 0 1 3|
```

So for N steps, you'd multiply with the matrix N times, which is the same as multiplying with the N-th power of the matrix.

```
                                |0 0 0 1| ^ N
                                |1 0 0 4|
final |A B C D|  =  |1 1 1 1| * |0 1 0 1|
                                |0 0 1 3|
```

Don't build large numbers, calculate modulo 10^10 throughout.

## Python

Pure Python implementation, doing matrix multiplication and [exponentiation by squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) myself. Took ~0.04 seconds for the large case.

```py
def matmul(A, B):
    return [
        [sum(a * b for a, b in zip(row, col)) % 10**10
         for col in zip(*B)]
        for row in A
    ]

def fast(N):
    P = [[1, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 1, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 1, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 1]]
    M = [[0, 0, 0, 1],
         [1, 0, 0, 4],
         [0, 1, 0, 1],
         [0, 0, 1, 3]]
    while N:
        if N % 2:
            P = matmul(P, M)
        M = matmul(M, M)
        N //= 2
    [[A, B, C, D]] = matmul([[1]*4], P)
    return D
```

Testing code:

```
from time import time

# Original implementation, used for testing
def solvePuzzle(N):
    var_A = 1
    var_B = 1
    var_C = 1
    var_D = 1
    for i in range(1, N + 1):
        result = 3 * var_D + 1 * var_C + 4 * var_B + 1 * var_A
        var_A = var_B
        var_B = var_C
        var_C = var_D
        var_D = result
    return var_D % 10000000000  # Last 10 digits of var_D

# Test correctness for N up to 1000
for N in range(1001):
    expect = solvePuzzle(N)
    result = fast(N)
    assert result == expect, (N, expect, result)

# Solve the challenge
t0 = time()
result = fast(2023 ** 100)
t1 = time()
print(f'{result=}, computed in {t1-t0:.3f} seconds')
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bVRLbtswEN10xVMMEBQRVaaR7CwKA174s6xVA-1OEArVpmwC-oGkktZBLtArdJNNeqiepkOK-gEmtJh58-WbEf_8rX_pc1W-vr41Orv79O_d7yPPoEh10eTeisGaLgjgkVw3soTYKubEqim8FHz4AVklIWUoiBIuovZk9cTgUOWUwnsIA98Pgz7MOqOt8_XXNCFjGwYb28qCCSGmnSxV2otcJ3tYQhyHDIL2S9iQPEYgvA47yxXYWJK2iZ3NPYLH3n3Jh-slw-sl5y7301nkHKJF7yMyiJCg2YB013P07xnsaG_cDYbdxBDB_f0SZlaPYzMzBhsG2yQZIpCwxMe-YU_H49wSQjJZFaBFwUEUdSW1lQm5gS9SnESZ5gbPecFLnWpRlQwaxY92VporLcqTnZGq8ke-by6XnPejekzl9xU2EfbaeqJtJtq210xuYbZApuWJe0hiBB8gpANTkqsm1xgwxw1sg9HByRuUH5y8HuGrPrxrzHpM0LVDNxN049DtBDUNt42MOW0tZvH7A3ADn3GHEYMjkqoVVJlLiER_Qxrxn5CSH3TJlbL3j6CpQVc2DWmBgZAg6MjgP2uMwkam_JMJSe7_sWCqFMchd7aly8DAi1gvt1Zqmvtq8oI-czic0zznWJ_oAJOaNfEomRaZBTOciG-6pkSHg1stRam97Pa59V--mBeiqBuNq4T3etbhnQ4WH-fZCyh-qMqjuqXtk-Repu6F-g8)

## Python + NumPy

Here I used a little class to represent integers modulo 10^10 that supports multiplication and addition, and used NumPy for the matrix power. Solving the large case took ~0.17 seconds.

```py
# Integers modulo 10**10
class Int:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value % 10**10
    def __int__(self):
        return self.value
    def __add__(self, other):
        return Int(int(self) + int(other))
    def __mul__(self, other):
        return Int(int(self) * int(other))
    __rmul__ = __mul__
    __radd__ = __add__

M = np.matrix([
    [0, 0, 0, Int(1)],
    [1, 0, 0, Int(4)],
    [0, 1, 0, Int(1)],
    [0, 0, 1, Int(3)],
], dtype=object)

def fast(N):
    # Compute final (A,B,C,D) and return D as int
    return int(([1]*4 * M**N)[0, 3])
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=lVTNbtswDL7spKcgEBS1PTWwkh6GAjnk5zJgzQZstyAwvFhOPNiSIctFf9An2aWX7qH2FnuDUT92bHSXCQFCfiQ_kTSpn7_qB32S4uXltdX51Yff7_4UVS2VBtFW9QOkDYia5EpWoIuKgzcamRAygc-qOBYiLY2h5BUXOtWFFBTahmeQSwWaN7oQR5LxHBpZ3vEv7eNjyYNteEMAz12qkiUsgPXaaqStR9rGalY15AUUAlQqjjxgFLbwHpinNUfxpi01Rswh8tHo4OU1ytdeXg3wZR_eZWY9RujKo-sRuvboZoSajF0iLm3FdauEN10Ai_sDMIFPaaMRgwzbqhuQ-YDR9Puj0PzIVQOVzNpSomsUsZgcyrRpjNEVb3qdJIUodJIEDS9zijRlywe9MejUgjZr83_RsQ0pOoZRW20FZ4ZBQJpl_ZVSn7h6G4dZBsjrWLHxRnau4YCoasv_I4reECWJsixYoOfrYJulha1EyC0qop5WqVbFfbCzfruYgvuZi1i4pw5mQ_i6hxFg__B2rszBcwPvKWT6oeYL-f0HP-iQ2NXI8cP3OzGBtazqVnPI7XIFS7qia7oJIRVZV_7GLCfWPJwq04Jgx_aRmezbKNqGJoH5PjSz8w03EQ5SKbxVcJwXs0FbaGvQ0s4hccB5peK4Wyd-X2MUdmm8wmS0Zr4GC-I8cnwoOtvCM1AItrSXndUm99XwAn49OJzSsuR4P9ExkpqnJgjJ-JJZPMOdjkzWIdHs7FYr04L88sn5L54pVmxbmZm6njS70vHNdJY_4_wepMiay9C9fP4B7B7Cvw)

### Ruby

Bonus: A Ruby implementation, where I did exponentiation by squaring myself so I could apply modulo after each step. I'm a Ruby newb, so this can perhaps be improved.

```rb
require 'matrix'

m = Matrix[
  [0, 0, 0, 1],
  [1, 0, 0, 4],
  [0, 1, 0, 1],
  [0, 0, 1, 3]
]

n = 2023 ** 100
power = 1
while n > 0
  if n % 2 > 0
    power *= m
    power.map! { |x| x % 10**10 }
  end
  m *= m
  m.map! { |x| x % 10**10 }
  n /= 2
end

p (Matrix[[1,1,1,1]] * power)[0, 3] % 10**10
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=fZBBDgExFIZj-07xWwhq0M5Y2HADJ5AuiIpJdIxmJkZwEhsLLuU03ugMVtKm6df3_23ff727fHm83R55tu6Pn42eM_s8dgZtu8hcXLSJLCaYvWFOwFwG8FPpoGRV88hzWfmtV-IAkSZNlPBtoQwjCAElJaW7g3F8puiwibcGCaaQ7IvXvG0hrBDwQjGB_eLALtImTjgXZxSsVlIIJXFhhUlWvNraYP9IEwz5T1Q6KEWn6pUbew-tIfxr3bKXSH_MPrMqujrCFw)